# Split a list from some element and getting the item values into another list in Python 2.7

Tags: python, list

This is my list:

```
l = ['today','is','a','holiday','but','nothing','to','do']
```

I wish to put the items after 'but' into another list such as:

```
another_list = ['nothing','to','do']
```

I tried the following way:

```
l = ['today','is','a','holiday','but','nothing','to','do']
for element in l:
   parts = element.split('but')
```

But it does not provide the output I expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are splitting on an array element not a string.. so in this case you a split isn't going to work. There is nothing to split. Instead find the index and continue from there. Checkout https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm to learn more about python list

```
l = ['today','is','a','holiday','but','nothing','to','do']
# get the index of but
i = l.index("but") # "This method returns index of the found object otherwise raise an exception indicating that value does not find."
# print everything after "but" using slice logic.
print l[i+1:]
```

Comment: should be `l[i+1:]`

Comment: Thank you,I will refer your link to get more knowledge about list.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `index`:

```
l[l.index('but')+1:]
>>> ['nothing', 'to', 'do']
```

Comment: Weird behavior when "but" is not found

Answer (score 2):

Join the list, partition it, and then re-split it.

```
' '.join(l).partition('but')[-1].split() # ['nothing', 'to', 'do']
```